# 体格 vs スタイル When to use which

Tags: word-choice, words, word-usage

Not sure on the difference between these two words.  Is there any real difference in how they are used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

体格 is more of a human body shape to describe like skinny, normal, fat, masculine, etc. It is used in a neutral way.

スタイル tends to describe one's outlook in an affirmative way. (e.g. tall and skinny has been considered to be suitable for a fashion model)